# How to hide space for image when no images found in the server?

Tags: html, css

I have data aggregator, organize the data from different source by specific manner.

Sometimes the images given in the source type is not available or the source refused to serve the images. In this case, I want to remove the space given for image tag. Is it possible?
[image]

I want to hide the highlighted area space when no image found or serve refused to serve the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to use the `onerror` function. Something like this:

`<img src="image_not_found.jpg" onerror="this.style.display = 'none';" alt="">`

You can find out more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053(v=vs.85).aspx

**edit**

Even though this will work for all the browsers, using the `onerror` attribute will make your HTML invalid since it is not part of the `img` attribute list. An article on the pros and cons for using this attribute. http://blog.sociomantic.com/2010/07/html-onerror-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Comment: Bleh, please use [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers) rather than MSDN's JScript docs. I'm pretty sure that the `onerror` attribute on images is not part of [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/). [From what I see there](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents), `onerror` is only valid on `object`, `body`, and `frameset` elements.

Comment: @Matt, According to the MDC documentation as well you can have the `onerror` attribute for image tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/image

Comment: @sarcastyx: that's [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL), not the DOM element.

Comment: @Matt, I am pretty sure I did read that `onerror` was part of the attribute list a while ago. But I might have been wrong. Have edited my answer. Thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: I'm surprised - this [does actually work!](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7dtvq/1/). +1

Comment: Yup. It works like a charm. Maybe that is why I thought it was always part of the spec.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution I can think of: set the server up so that it sends back a 1px * 1px image instead of `404`ing.

Comment: On second thought I don't think he can do this :( `"data aggregator, organize the data from different source"`. It doesn't sound like he controls the server.

Comment: @thirtydot: I noticed that as well in the question, but it's not clear to me, so I'm just waiting for a response from the OP.

Comment: the servers are not in my control.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to do it all client-side (and have image links to other servers that you don't control as well), you can run a [javascript function](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/89) over those images to determine if they're loaded successfully, and if not, set their `jsObject.style.display = 'none'` for jsObject being each image that didn't load.

Or try [this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0083.html) for replacing images that failed to load with a specified "missing" placeholder image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control of the server-side code, you can use JavaScript. Since I don’t see a “broken image” that a browser uses when the `src` of an image element is broken I’m assuming the container is just empty.

Assuming the container of the image has a class called `.container`, you can use this snippet of code if you have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.container').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "") {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

});
```

Or better yet, with **CSS** alone, still assuming the container element has a class name called `.container`:

```
.container:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I think your basic idea is fine, but the actual test (if the innerHTML is empty) will not work.

Comment: Then what do you suggest I test it against?